# How can I put Korean as an argument in find_element_by_link_text() in Python - Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

I'm using Selenium in Python 3.4.

I tried to put a Korean word as an argument in the `find_element_by_link_text()` method, but it doesn't work.

What I mean is that it did not create any errors but it cannot find any hyperlink whose text is Korean.

Here is some example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('www.certain-korean-web-page.com')
a = browser.find_element_by_link_text('한국말')
print(a)
```

And it raises `NoSuchElementException` even though the page source has that element (of course, I checked an English one and it works).

Is it a unicode problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Thanks.

Comment: Done with adding example :)

Comment: The current example isn't reproducible since nothing exists at that URL.

Comment: Your example uses `find_element_by_name()`, not `find_element_by_text()`...

Comment: @taleinat If you want Korean site url : http://www.naver.com. And corrected my mistake :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

couldn't find the element mentioned in your code on naver.com. but tried with another element and its working fine for me. code below.

```
# coding=utf-8
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.naver.com/')
a = browser.find_element_by_link_text('네이버뉴스')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must add the line below at the top of project_file.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Then include this line:

```
a = browser.find_element_by_link_text(u'한국말')
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: It will only work for sure if the source file is saved UTF-8.  The comment declares the source encoding only, so if it is not UTF-8, it won't work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't agree with you. python has got interpreter so whenever the file has been run, utf-8 encoding will be read by python interpreter.So, it must be present in source code when we wanna write utf-8 stuff in source code. On the other hand (u'한국말') has worked for me exactly in this situation. So please let me know where the problem of my script is.Thanks dear

Comment: The source encoding comment tells the Python interpreter what bytes were used to encode the file.  Try your code but save it in an encoding other than UTF-8.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the example. I thought the problem was something else